# Application Defined Object Defined error- Excel VBA Vlookup. Works on one file but not others

Tags: excel, error-handling, vlookup, vba

I'm working with two workbooks and I'm trying to use V-Lookup. My lookup values are in WB1, Sheet 2 and their corresponding values are in WB2, Sheet 1. My Macro is run on WB1 and the Macro Opens a dialog box for the user to select the file for WB2. Then the information about the file such as FileName, File path are stored.

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
RangeName = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(0, 1).Address

Workbooks(wb1).Activate

Range("D1:D" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "!" & RangeName & ",7,False)"
```

When I tested it on one file, the Vlookup values showed up. But on my second file, it keeps giving me the error Application Defined or Object Defined Error. It's literally the same code. The error happens on the Vlookup line.  Why is this happening?

Comment: There are many possible reasons. `1-` spaces in file names or sheet names. `2-` VLooukup did not find any match. `3-` CurrentRegion is not reliable (try using `UsedRange` instead of `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`). `4-` using the activate stuff make things worse, though probably not the source of the current error.

Comment: You could **try** changing `[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "!"` to `'[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!"` and see whether it helps.  That should get around most errors caused by invalid characters (such as space) in filenames / sheetnames.

Comment: Can someone explain what the error message means? What does Application Defined or Object Defined error imply?

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions on other ways in this situation to use VLOOKUP (doesn't have to be VLOOKUP specifically, just something that functions as VLOOKUP). For some reason, Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup or Application.Vlookup does not work. Maybe I'm not writing the code properly. My situation is a little complicated because I am using two workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the whole string representing the lookup range's address with `external:=true`.

```
with ActiveSheet
    RangeName = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(0, 1).Address(external:=true)
end with
```

Your formula assignment becomes,

```
Workbooks(wb1).worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D" & LastRow).Formula = _
  "=VLOOKUP(A1, " & RangeName & ", 7, False)"
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Literally saved a life! :)